# PHP display error in md5() function

Tags: php

I tried to assign a salt to md5() function along with the password parameter. But PHP is displaying an error message when the code is executed.

> An error message **Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference**
>   is displayed when I try to execute the following code. I tried to assign the reference to a variable and pass it to the md5() function. But still PHP is displaying the same error message.

```
    global $Database;
    if ($stmt = $Database -> prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? and password = ?")) {
        $salt = $this->salt;
        $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $user, md5($pass . $salt));
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> store_result();

        if ($stmt -> num_rows > 0) {
            $stmt -> close();
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            $stmt -> close();
            return FALSE;
        }
    } else {
        die("ERROR: Could not prepare MySQLI statement");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bind_param`'s `params` need references to variables. You cannot use `md5()` directly, you'll need to assign it to a variable first:

```
md5pass = md5($pass . $salt);
```

Then, use it:

```
$stmt -> bind_param("ss", $user, $md5pass);
```

**Tip:** Please don't use `md5()` for hashing passwords. You can use `crypt()` with blowfish algorithm as it is much more secure.